# Generating list items on button click a limited number of times

Tags: javascript

I want to generate maximum three new list items on button click but my code is not working, what is wrong?

```
function addListItem() { 
   for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){  
   var newLi  = document.createElement("LI"); 
   var liText = document.createTextNode("new"); 
   newLi.appendChild(liText); 
   document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newLi); 
   }; 
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f755reut/

Comment: *" want to generate maximum three new list items..."* -- Why `i < 4`? It should be `i < 3`.

Comment: First important note: this code creates **exactly four** items. What do you mean by "maximum three"? Second important note: your Fiddle isn't working, because your function is declared in window ready, but not in body. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/f755reut/1/.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it should generate one list item on button click and stop when it reached three generated items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/f755reut/3/

You count how many items you generated, and when you reached 3 - don't let it add more.

```
var itemsGenerated = 0;

function addListItem() {
  if (itemsGenerated < 3) {
    var newLi = document.createElement("LI");
    var liText = document.createTextNode("new");
    newLi.appendChild(liText);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newLi);
    itemsGenerated++;
  }
};
```